# Search on multiple terms with Elastic Search

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm new to ES and want to setup a query to search on multiple terms.

My SQL looks like:

```
"SELECT field4 FROM tablename WHERE (field1 = 'A' OR field1 = 'AA') AND (field2 = 'B' OR fields2 = 'BB') AND (field3 = 'C' OR field3 = 'CC')"
```

In ES I'm trying

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "term": {
        "field1": {"A","AA"}
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "field2": {"B","BB"}
      }
    },
    {
    "term": {
      "field3": {"C","CC"}
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you most likely want is a `terms` query. You can see the documentation for it here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

An example from that site is:

```
{
    "terms" : { "user" : ["kimchy", "elasticsearch"]}
}
```

Also, your query right now isn't valid json, you'll need to correct it.

Comment: I tried the following but still not working.:       {  "from": 0,  "size": 200,  "query": {  "bool": {  "must": {  "bool": {  "must": [  {  "bool": {  "should": [  {  "term": {  "field2": "1"  }  },  {  "term": {  "field2": "4"  }  }  ]  }  },  {  "bool": {  "should": [  {  "term": {  "field1": "1"  }  },  {  "term": {  "field1": "3"  }  }  ]  }  }  ]  }  }  }  }  }

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the result of running the query? Does it error or just return zero results? If the latter, you probably don't have any documents that match the query. Double check what documents you have in the elasticsearch cluster and try a simpler query to confirm the documents are there and you are running the query correctly.